# Create account trigger for create contact modal aura component

Tags: trigger, aura

Good day. I have a modal window for creating a contact with the fields name, surname, phone number, email and account, all fields are made with usual inputs. I need to create a trigger when creating a contact, the account name is indicated in writing without any lookups, if there is one, the trigger binds to it, if not, the trigger creates a new account and binds to it. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Unless you pass in the name as a separate field, you can't do this. The component itself should query the Account table and select an appropriate record, and/or restrict the user from saving until they select an Account.

Comment: @sfdcfox What I've actually understood from this post is that the Account is passed via the text field, but would be nice if Сергей could confim. Not like it would make things easier as it's just about creating a lookup field then, but who knows. The [Strike Lookup](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/blob/master/aura/strike_lookup/strike_lookup.cmp) could be a solution if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, the account field has a text field. The fact of the matter is that the task is to make the field not a lookup, but an input. As for me, I would make a lookup and everyone would live fine. And here it is the task to make an input field and write a trigger that will check whether there is an account or not, if there is, it will add the created contact to the existing account, and if not, it will, in addition to creating a contact, create a new account and bind to it